What does a letter "R" means in a helipad?
What does it means when a helipads has a letter "R" and a arrow?
Here are some examples and the link to google maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/heliport/@35.4638657,139.6262343,40m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu

https://www.google.com/maps/search/heliport/@35.5238752,139.6749923,40m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu

Ⓡ is for Emergency Rescue/Response (not "restricted" as I thought first). According to this post on Quora: Buildings above a certain height are required to have such helipad. It is used in case of disaster, e.g. a earthquake, when streets are not usable to assist/to evacuate. This kind of requirement is also found in Korea, likely for the same reasons. According to another post, they are seldom used, and Volocopter is looking to use them as vertiports.

(Source)

i see, and do you know what the arrow means? I've seen some have one and two arrows.

@Gabe: I've no idea, possibly to indicate how to evacuate the helipad once landed.

If I remember correctly, those helipad cannot be used as normal helipad because they do not respect the minimum dimension for a helipad. They can only be used in case of emergency.

Im pretty sure the arrow indicates which direction the tail should point

I think the arrow is the direction the helipad should be approached, as to maximize clearance with the structure and surrounding buildings.

@user71659, are you sure? If I look at the 2nd satellite image in the OP, it seems like approaching from the South maintains more clearance to the objects on the roof than the east-west directions indicated by the arrows.

@ROIMaison Look at the image in 3D view. Approaching from the South would send the helicopter right into a giant cooling tower.
